# Make Stylelint ignore indentation in certain instances?

Tags: css, stylelint

I recently set up Stylelint to run through my stylesheets but there's an error it's throwing that I'd rather keep as-is:

[image]

The error is that I'm not using a single space before the `{` and while I'd like this to be true for most other instances for legibility I was hoping to keep this one.

Is it possible to either modify the rule to allow these sorts of indentation patterns or otherwise disable a rule for a block of CSS? The latter is not ideal but I'll take what I can get.

Otherwise I'll likely just ignore it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the rule in question is [`block-opening-brace-space-before`](https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint/blob/master/lib/rules/block-opening-brace-space-before/README.md).

If you want to only enforce a single space before the opening brace of *multiline blocks* and ignore *single-line blocks*, then you can do so using the rule's [`always-multi-line`](https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint/blob/master/lib/rules/block-opening-brace-space-before/README.md#always-multi-line) primary option:

```
/* Enforce a single space before this opening brace */
a {
  color: red;
}

/* Don't enforce anything before this opening brace */
a    { color: red; }
```

There is, however, no option to specifically ignore the opening braces of *single-line keyframe declaration blocks*. If this is what you want then please raise a feature request issue.

> Is it possible to either modify the rule to allow these sorts of indentation patterns

You can [create a plugin](https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint/blob/master/docs/developer-guide/plugins.md) that *enforces* the alignment of the open braces of single-line keyframe declaration blocks within each @keyframe.

> otherwise disable a rule for a block of CSS?

You can use [stylelint-disable](https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint/blob/master/docs/user-guide/configuration.md#turning-rules-off-from-within-your-css) commands to turn off the `block-opening-brace-space-before` rule for this block of code.

Comment: I ended up using the disabling commands. I'm not sure how I feel about this as a long-term solution but it'll do for now. Thanks!